# Generically add controls and post to server in ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have a situation where the user has to enter multiple orderslines to an order. It can be 1, it can be 100. More orderlines should be added by clicking a small (+) sign, which adds more textboxes on the fly without a postback.

I am limited to ASP.NET web forms, newest version.

**My initial code**:

I had hoped I could write a script like this:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#moreBtn').click(function() {
            addNewControl();
        });
    });

    function addNewControl() {

        var orderLineDivId = "orderlinesDiv" + count;
        var orderLineTitleId = "orderlines_title" + count;
        var orderLineValueId = "orderlines_value" + count;

        var parent = $('#<%=OrderLinesPnl.ClientID %>');

        var newCtl = '<div id="'+orderLineDivId+'">' +
            '<div id="' + orderLineTitleId + '"><input type="text" /></div>' +
            '<div id="' + orderLineValueId + '"><input type="text" /></div>' +
            '</div>';

        parent.append(newCtl);
    }

</script>
```

And then on the code behind:

```
OrderLinesPnl.FindControl("orderlinesDiv1");
```

But it seems that FindControl needs to find a control, and I add simple HTML elements.

Code I have:

```
   <h3>Orderlines</h3>

    <a id="moreBtn" href="#">(+)</a>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="OrderLinesPnl">

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitBtn" Text="Create product" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click"/>
```

So basically: on the server side, I need a way to iterate all controls added, and retrieve their content.

**EDIT: My working code**

```
<script>
        var count = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#moreBtn').click(function() {
                addNewControl();
            });
        });

        function addNewControl() {

            var orderLineDivId = "orderlinesDiv" + count;
            var orderLineTitleId = "orderlines_title" + count;
            var orderLineValueId = "orderlines_value" + count;

            var parent = $('#<%=OrderLinesPnl.ClientID %>');

            var newCtl = '<div id="'+orderLineDivId+'">' +
                '<div><input id="' + orderLineTitleId + '" name="' + orderLineTitleId + '" type="text" /></div>' +
                '<div><input id="' + orderLineValueId + '" name="' + orderLineValueId + '" type="text" /></div>' +
                '</div>';

            parent.append(newCtl);
            count++;
        }

    </script>
```

Then I can get the values from the `this.Request.Form;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping to unexisting controls, you can just read the bare POST:

```
this.Request.Form
```

This gives you a low-level key-value collection you can iterate over. The only small isue with web forms is that web forms is a paranoiac when it comes to security and posting to nonexisting controls will likely raise a validation exception. Just turn off validation for the page or write a custom request validator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: as for your comment, your controls lack the `name` property and thus their values are not sent to the server. Just make them have names.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see my dynamically added input controls in the POST, as it is web forms?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard: Controls that lack name property are not included in POST, that is how browsers work. This has nothing to do with asp.net. Your controls seem to have ids rather than names.

Comment: I turned off validation, gave them a name but they still don't turn up in the 'this.Request.Form' . Is there some filter?

Comment: Did you give names to inputs or to divs?

Comment: No, I am an idiot, and I should feel bad. Thanks! Everything works now

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would suggest to get all the values you want to send to the server put them in a json and send them with Ajax to your function in Code Behind.

You can serialize the form data like below :

```
 var frm = $(document.myform);
 var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

The url you will post will be

```
url: "Default.aspx/OnSubmit"
```

In Code Behind you must decorate your function as Web Method in order for the Ajax to post to this function.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string OnSubmit(string datafilds)
    {
        //parse the json
        //save to the database
        return "OK";
    }
```